# Simple test but invalid locator :-(

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, typescript, protractor

I have this test:

```
// import {by, element, browser} from "protractor";
describe('intro', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get('');
  });

it('should have multiple pages', () => {
    let buttonOnward = element(by.linkText('Continue'));
    expect(element.all(buttonOnward).count()).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

And get this result.

```
1) intro should have multiple pages
  Message:
    Failed: Invalid locator
  Stack:
    TypeError: Invalid locator
        at Object.check [as checkedLocator] (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js:267:9)
        at WebDriver.findElements (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:919:18)
        at C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:161:44
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)
        at C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should have multiple pages") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:79:14)
        at C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:16:5
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.describe (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\intro_spec.ts:11:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\intro_spec.ts:2:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
```

And I don't know why. Its really simple. I downloaded the typings for Jasmine and checked this file `C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js`.

There is a function defined for it:

[image: The defined function in by.js]

And the documentation says the function exists, too.

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText

```
$ protractor --version
Version 4.0.9
$ npm -v
3.10.8
$ node -v
v6.7.0
```

Thanks in Advance for your ideas!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To extend @Gunderson's answer a little bit more. The main problem is that you are using an `ElementFinder` (the result of `element()` call) instead of a `by` locator. See how the `buttonOnward` is defined:

```
let buttonOnward = element(by.linkText('Continue'));
```

Now, you are using the `buttonOnward`, which is now an `ElementFinder` in place of a locator:

```
expect(element.all(buttonOnward).count()).toBe(1);
```

which, understandably, results into an "invalid locator" error.

---

What you meant is using the "by" locator instead:

```
expect(element.all(by.linkText('Continue')).count()).toBe(1);
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your error has to do with the `linkText` locator at all, your problem is with `expect(element.all(buttonOnward).count()).toBe(1);`, that is an invalid locator.  If you want to count the total buttons, you should just declare your locator like that:

```
let buttonOnward = element.all(by.linkText('Continue'));
expect(buttonOnward.count()).toBe(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using `browser.driver.findElement`. This means I was using the Selenium API. However, the Selenium API apparently doesn't support `by.model` locators. However, the **Protractor** API does include support for the [`by.model` locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model), and to use the **Protractor** API I use the `element` function instead:

Doesn't Work:

```
//This would not work: 
//error  E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Invalid locator
browser.driver.findElement(by.model('login_form.email'))
```

Works:

```
//But this works; note it uses the `element` function 
//instead of `browser.driver.findElement`
element(by.model('login_form.email'))
```

Also Works:

```
//And this also works; note it uses `browser.driver.findElement`
//But it passes a different locator; not `by.model`, but `by.id`
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('#login_form_email'))
```

Note:

The Protractor `by.model` locator will ultimately [call a CSS `querySelectorAll`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/a62efc6e401bc1aa7408e3008ccdaa219b528636/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L578) by prefixing with `'ng-model'`. It makes sense that Protractor adds `by.model` locator functionality because Protractor is more Angular-focused.

I am assuming Selenium doesn't support `by.model` natively because the "Model" locator is [not listed among Selenium (Java) locators on this page](https://selenium-webdriver.com/java/locators)

- Id
- Name
- ClassName
- CSS
- Xpath
- How to op

[Nor in this Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) list of Selenium methods.